# adding jar files in dataproc cluster Initialization script for Jupyter usage

Tags: pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc

I have a requirement to read xlsx files and create Avro files, but the GCP Cluster does not have these jars.

1. My Pyspark process is using sources excel and Avro.
   I would like to include the jars for these in the cluster creation Terraform script by calling a cluster_startup.sh
   What should be the contents of the  cluster_startup.sh for excel and Avro jars

```
initialization_action
{
      script      = "gs://bucket_name/cluster_startup.sh"

      timeout_sec = 500    
}
```

If any additional information is needed in this script like maven dependencies for Avro, please provide that details.

2. I would like to invoke the jars like below in pyspark Jupyter

Please note we do not have access to terminal/shell/external internet for git, so this has to be invoked in the Pyspark jupyter only.

Where will these jars be saved during the cluster creation initialization process?

excel_jar=f"gs://{bucket_name}/com.crealytics:spark-excel_2.11:0.13.0"

avro_jar=f"gs://{bucket_name}/spark-avro-assembly-3.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"

```
spark = SparkSession.builder \
.master("local") \
.appName("Word Count") \
.config("spark.jars",excel_jar,avro_jar) \
.getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel") \
.option("useHeader", "true") \
.option("inferSchema", "true") \
.option("dataAddress", "'NameOfYourExcelSheet'!A1") \
.load("your_file"))

df.write.format("avro").save("/tmp/output/test.avro")
```

Please provide the required details.

Comment: There are several options: 1) use init action to download the jars to `/usr/lib/spark/jars`; 2) add `spark.jars` with URIs or `spark.jars.packages` with package names. I noticed in your code, seems you are mixing URI and package name. And You need to join `excel_jar` and `avro_jar` with `,` as a single string.

Comment: @Dagang, can you please post your comment as answer?

Comment: @Dagang, Thank you for your response. Can you please provide  exact content of this shell script for these jars to be saved at required location

Comment: Say your jars are in `gs://my-bucket/jars`, then the init action would be `gsutil cp gs://my-bucket/jars/*.jar /usr/lib/spark/jars/`.

Comment: @ScottB sure, done.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options:

1. When creating the cluster, use an init action to download the jars to `/usr/lib/spark/jars`. Say your jars are in `gs://my-bucket/jars/`, then the init action would be `gsutil cp gs://my-bucket/jars/*.jar /usr/lib/spark/jars/`.
2. Or add `spark.jars` with jar URIs (e.g., `gs://{bucket_name}/spark-avro-assembly-3.1.0-SNAPSHOT.ja`) or `spark.jars.packages` with package names (e.g., `com.crealytics:spark-excel_2.11:0.13.0`). I noticed in your code, seems you are mixing URI and package name. And You need to join `excel_jar` and `avro_jar` with , as a single string. The properties can be used as command line flag when submitting Spark/PySpark jobs with gcloud or spark-submit, or as code in Jupyter notebooks.

Comment: Same error
 Failed to find data source: com.crealytics.spark.excel.
def session_create(app_name, jars=[]): 
  configuration = (SparkConf()
      .set("spark.jars", ','.join(jars)))
  spark = pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder.appName(app_name) \
    .config(conf=configuration).getOrCreate()
  return spark
app_name = 'test_app'
jars = ['gs://qwiklabs/test_bucket/spark-excel_2.11_uber-0.12.0.jar']
spark = session_create(app_name,jars)
df = spark.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel") \
          .option("useHeader","true") \
          .load(path)

Comment: I am  testing this on Vertex AI Workbench, please suggest.

Comment: I don't know why but `spark.jars` and `spark.jars.packages` should work. Have you tried init action?

Comment: Not yet, we would like to go with spark.jars. 
Somehow i dont see the dataproc cluster name in the available Kernal list.
This might be causing the issue.
Could you please suggest how can we activate the dataproc cluster in the Workbench Jupyter Kernal.